# L20N translate html after DOM changed

Tags: javascript, web-applications, translation, l20n

I am trying to implement L20n in a simple knockout based website but I have run into some issues.

I have my views created dynamically.
How can I force html to be translated again once my DOM has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't in the docs yet, but L20n uses a Mutation Observer to react to any changes made to the DOM.  As long as you use the `data-l10n-id` attribute in your views code, the observer will pick up any dynamic changes made by Knockout and will retranslate the affected elements.

If you really need to force a retranslation, you can do so with [`translateFragment`](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/v3.x/docs/view.md#viewtranslatefragmentfrag):

```
document.l10n.translateFragment(document.body).then(…);
```